# present continuous and the word "yet"

Tags: present-continuous

1. If you are not using it yet.
2. If you haven't used it yet.

I heard the first one in a video and I feel the expression is odd to me. I would say the second one instead. So, is the first one grammatically correct? If it is, dose it mean the same thing as the latter?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, both are grammatically correct. (2) suggests that 'it' is something you use for short periods of time, like a toothbrush. (1) could refer to something that will be in continuous use, like a heater that you will switch on when the weather gets colder.

Comment: So, is (1) commonly used in everyday communication or used rarely?

Comment: Yes, both are quite common; which one you choose depends on the kind of 'use' you are referring to, as I explained.

Comment: Does the present continuous tense used in (1) emphasize **the process** of _(not) using it_?

Comment: It assumes that the person addressed will soon start, or may have already started, to use the item continuously or frequently.